# How to add custom function in pepper plugin API

Tags: javascript, ppapi

As title, can I add a custom function in pepper plugin API?

Can the custom function return a value?

like this

```
HelloTutorialModule = document.getElementById('hello_tutorial');
var errorCode;
errorCode = HelloTutorialModule.myCustomFunction('Hello');
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes, you can, because `document.getElementById` will return an `Object`, you can enhance this object if it is not `freeze`.

Please refer to my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w55p29r3/)

Comment: Object of JS is open, you can override or add code of any Object expect of frozen Object.